# Removed App Icon After That New package not yet registered with the system Message Encountered

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, apk, emulation

In my application i have removed the application icon programatically like

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),     
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

after that the application installs and works fine but when i try to re-install the application after some changes it gives following

> New package not yet registered with the system

any thing im doing worng ...

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The error accures because you disabled that Activity completly in the Android Package Manager. In the first run it´s fine because I think you have defined activity-alias in your Manifest with a new shortcut. But when you update your App, the App tries to start the disabled Launcher and boom you can´t start it cause disabled. A (not perfect) workaround would be the following:

```
       <activity
            android:name="com.example.Your_Launchscreen"
            android:icon="@drawable/your_alternative_icon"
            android:label="NotRealAppname"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

 <activity-alias
            android:name=".Launchscreen_2"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/real_app_name"
            android:targetActivity=".Your_Launchscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

Now in your Activity:

```
getPackageManager().
setComponentEnabledSetting(newComponentName(
activity,Your_Launchscreen.class.getName()+"_2"),
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
Toast.makeText(activity, "Real Appicon hidden...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and for showing it again:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = 
new ComponentName(activity,Your_Launchscreen.class.getName()+"_2");
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
Toast.makeText(activity, "Real Appicon visible again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This solution is not perfect, because after App installation you have 2 App icons. The real icon and the hidden one. But you can now hide the real icon and update your App without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply ignore this message.

It will **only appear after reinstall with adb** trying to start the activity which is not registered anymore. You should start the app manually.